# How to use SQL to query a column based on a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table and assume we are given a number.

Lets say 2 and we want to find all rows in a column **name** which **ends**
with 2. In this case b2.

```
Personid  Ac1     b2         yt3
 ===============================
      1   Red     small      54
      2   Green   Big        22
      3   Red     Big        21
```

So far I have no been able to find an answer.(every column name ends with a unique number)

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I need to somehow find the column names and then see which one end with 2

Comment: Yes, and you can't "find the column names" within a query. You need to find the column names in the metadata (`sys.columns`), then build a query using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hmmm, why not I know they are all in a system table.

Comment: Because that's not how T-SQL works - the columns and other entity names in the query you ultimately submit to SQL Server need to be well-defined. You need to build the query dynamically; you can't just join your table to system catalogs to determine which column(s) to return at runtime. You might want to consider a different design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic query with some trick.
You get columns from information_schema table for this table with xml trick in format `b2,d2` and then replace `*` with this string, getting as a result `select b2,d2 from TestColumns`. The pass this statement to `EXEC` function:

```
CREATE TABLE TestColumns
    (
      a1 INT ,
      b2 INT ,
      c3 INT ,
      d2 INT
    )
GO

INSERT  INTO TestColumns
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 2, 2, 2 )


DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select * from TestColumns'
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = ( SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + COLUMN_NAME AS [text()]
                                                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                                WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'TestColumns'
                                                        AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%2'
                                              FOR
                                                XML PATH('')
                                              ), 1, 1, '')
                              )


SET @s = REPLACE(@s, '*', @cols)

EXEC  (@s)
```

Output:

```
b2  d2
1   1
2   2
```

If you have unique indexed columns then you can simplify to:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select * from TestColumns'
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX) = ( SELECT   COLUMN_NAME
                               FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                               WHERE    TABLE_NAME = 'TestColumns'
                                        AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%2'
                             )

SET @s = REPLACE(@s, '*', @col)

EXEC  (@s)
```

Comment: This can be simpler, since the OP stated that each column name ends with a unique number, so there won't be `b2` *and* `d2`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this below query for that:

```
DECLARE @Str nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT '
DECLARE @TableName varchar(max) = 'yourTable', @PostFix int = 2

SELECT 
    @Str = @Str + '[' + t.name + '].[' + c.name + '],'
FROM 
    sys.tables t 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.columns c ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
WHERE 
    t.name = @TableName
    AND 
    c.name like '%' + CAST(@PostFix AS varchar(2))

SET @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, 1, LEN(@Str) - 1) + ' FROM ' + @TableName

EXEC(@Str)
```